# how to move folders to another folder in command line

Tags: command-line

I want to move everything in batch folder to previous folder including all folders in batch
but this command only moves files, not folders

```
move S:\Study\Study\batch\*  S:\Study\Study\
```

Comment: Welcome on superuser. Could you please provide us with some more info? Specifically: what OS are you using - some Windows variant, I assume? More towards an answer: did you try: move S:\Study\Study\batch\* S:\Study\Study\

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows commandline: move all subfolders' contents to parent](http://superuser.com/questions/671636/windows-commandline-move-all-subfolders-contents-to-parent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can be done using `for /r` or more easily using `xcopy /e` to copy the entire directory tree, including empty ones, and then deleting the original directory:

## solution 1: internal command

```
for /r source %a in (.) do @move %a destination
```

### notes

- **source** can be absolute or relative path to the directory
- **destination** should be the name of new non-existing directory, else the directory itself (*root*) will be moved into the existing directory

---

## solution 2: external command

```
xcopy /e source destination
rmdir /s /q source
```

### notes

- the command is executed by `%windir%\system32\xcopy.exe` executable file
- if **destination** does not exist, the user will be prompted whether **destination** specifies file (**f**) or directory (**d**) name