# Move files and folders to a subfolder

Tags: script

Hi I have a directory where I have many subfolders. In each subfolder, I have a folder called TEST along with other folders and files.

Subfolder1>Test, other folders, files
Subfolder2>Test, other folders, files

Could someone help me with writing a command line or batch file to move other folders and files into the test folder in each subfolder?

Desired solution would be

Subfolder1>Test>Other folders, files
Subfolder2>Test>Other folders, files

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to superuser. Is this is a homework assignment?

Answer (score 0):

If they are all one type of file or just a few types, you could do a *.file extension type search in the main folder and it should search all sub-folders by default I think or make sure in searches all folders e.g *.pdf would find all pdf files in main and all sub-folders, then copy them all to new folder n delete old when there safely in new folder.

Answer (score 0):

moving can be imitated by copying the tree (including empty directories) and then deleting it

```
xcopy /e source\ destination\
rmdir /s /q source\
```

[for a broader explanation](https://superuser.com/questions/831501/how-to-move-folders-to-another-folder-in-command-line/831502#831502)